# Cordova / Phonegap: Disable bounce only for header and footer

Tags: android, html, ios, css, cordova

I'm using this property inside the `config.xml` to disabe the bouncing of the webview (iOS):

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

This works as expected. But what if I only want to disable this bouncing for my header and footer? They are fixed at the top and bottom of my app, so I don't want them to bounce. But it would be more like a native feeling (especially for lists) when the inner container still has this bounce effect.

- Is there any way to achieve this? My header and my footer should not bounce, but my inner container should bounce.
- And is there also an iOS / Android cross compatible way?

Answer (score 4):

Just keep using

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

and in your CSS use the following code on your scrollable wrapper:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

It will give this bouncy effect to the scrollable content.

*overflow: hidden on your header and footer to avoid the user to scroll on it and overflow:scroll on your content plus the css webkit scrolling touch.*

Here is a JSFiddle [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mPfeQ/):
http://jsfiddle.net/mPfeQ/

***Note**:You should test it on a mobile device (it won't render on a computer)*

Comment: Thanks! It works with longer content. But what if the content doesn't need to scroll, because it's to short? Then you wouldn't have that bounce effect. When looking at native iOS lists, event with just one element, they have this bounce effect. Here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/mPfeQ/1/

Comment: Anyone an idea on this? When the content is too short, it doesn't bounce anymore

Comment: If anybody still has an idea, I would be glad to hear it. It still fails, when the content is too short

Comment: @23tux 4 years later: what about setting the contained div to `min-height: 100vh`?

Answer (score 1):

Hi simple add these CSS rules to list or scrolable elemet

```
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

**-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;** will give bounce effect to scrollling area (native look)